# How insert String value in XML formate

Tags: java, xml

```
    @POST
        @Path("/add")
        public Response addUser(
            @FormParam("fname") String fname,
            @FormParam("lname") String lname,@FormParam("mobile") String mobile,@FormParam("city") String city ,@FormParam("product") String product ) {
            java.util.Date d = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            String date=sd.format(d);
        //  Date xml_date=sd.parse(date);

            //XMLGregorianCalendar xml_date=DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(date);
            System.out.println("simple formate"+sd.format(d));
            System.out.println("String form"+date);

            int RM_ID=13455;
            String rm=Integer.toString(RM_ID);

            int sibel=1213;
            String sibel_val=Integer.toString(sibel);

            int emp=121;
            String emp_code=Integer.toString(emp);

            int branch=1212;
            String branch_code=Integer.toString(branch);

            int rq_id=12231;
            String req=Integer.toString(rq_id);

// This is xml object with Request.xml format so this xml tag, i want tag with string variables :

            String xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>"
                    +"<Create_BB_Lead mlns='http://www.kotak.com/Schemas/Create_BB_Lead_Req.xsd'>"
                        +"<RqUID></RqUID>"
                    +"<FIRST_NAME></FIRST_NAME>"
                        +"<LAST_NAME></LAST_NAME>"
                    +"<MOBILE></MOBILE>"
                        +"<PRODUCT_CODE></PRODUCT_CODE>"
                    +"<LOS_LOCATION></LOS_LOCATION>"
                        +"<SOURCE></SOURCE>"
                    +"<REMARKS></REMARKS>"
                        +"<RM_ID></RM_ID>"
                    +"<LEAD_TYPE></LEAD_TYPE>"
                        +"<SIEBEL_ID></SIEBEL_ID>"
                    +"<COMPANY_NAME></COMPANY_NAME>"
                        +"<EMP_CODE></EMP_CODE>"
                    +"<BRANCH_CODE></BRANCH_CODE>"
                        +"<LOGINID></LOGINID>"
                    +"<CREATED_DATE></CREATED_DATE>"
                        +"<CREATED_BY></CREATED_BY>"
                    +"</Create_BB_Lead>";

    //This is my xml object.
               xml.replaceAll("$RqUID", req);
            xml.replaceAll("$FIRST_NAME", fname);
            xml.replaceAll("$LAST_NAME", lname);
            xml.replaceAll("$MOBILE",mobile);
            xml.replaceAll("$PRODUCT_CODE", product);
            xml.replaceAll("$LOS_LOCATION", city);
            xml.replaceAll("$SOURCE", null);
            xml.replaceAll("$REMARKS", null);
            xml.replaceAll("$RM_ID",rm);
            xml.replaceAll("$LEAD_TYPE", null);
            xml.replaceAll("$SIEBEL_ID", sibel_val);
            xml.replaceAll("$COMPANY_NAME", null);
            xml.replaceAll("$EMP_CODE", emp_code);
            xml.replaceAll("$BRANCH_CODE", branch_code);
            xml.replaceAll("$LOGINID", null);
            xml.replaceAll("$CREATED_DATE", date);//2018-03-20
            xml.replaceAll("$CREATED_BY",fname);    

    System.out.println(xml);
            MakeApi api=new MakeApi();
            try {
                String response=api.invokeHTTPURL(url, xml);
                //System.out.println(response);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


I am passing the these string variables in xml tag. when i am passing these string variables getting those variables are not appended with the xml format.
```

Comment: is your xml object a plain string? could you publish some example?

Comment: no.i am converting xml object into string object then replace with tag value.

Comment: you have XML document that you want to convert to String , right ?

Comment: As an aside, I recommend you drop the long outdated `Date` class and the notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat`. Just use `String date = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toString();`. `LocalDate` is part of [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0):

in your case, I would totally use Velocity library to add info to your xml string. for example

```
VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
ve.init();

//set your variables        
VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
context.put("name", "Daniel");
context.put("message", "Hello Word");

//your template XML        
String strTemplate = "<xml><name>$name</name><msg>$message</msg></xml>";

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
ve.evaluate(context, writer, "error.log", strTemplate);

System.out.println( writer.toString() ); 
//<xml><name>Daniel</name><msg>Hello Word</msg></xml>
```

there are more optimal ways to do this, so I suggest you to check out a Velocity tutorial https://www.javaworld.com/article/2075966/core-java/start-up-the-velocity-template-engine.html

velocity maven repo https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.velocity/velocity/1.7

Comment: can we do without velocityengine

Comment: sure, you could go for regular expressions as well.

Comment: @suppose if we use string.replaceAll method. inside a method we pass the parameters

Answer (score 0):

Your XML template must at least look something like this:

```
        String xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>"
                +"<Create_BB_Lead mlns='http://www.kotak.com/Schemas/Create_BB_Lead_Req.xsd'>"
                    +"<RqUID>$RqUID</RqUID>"
                +"<FIRST_NAME>$FIRST_NAME</FIRST_NAME>"
                    +"<LAST_NAME>$LAST_NAME</LAST_NAME>"
                ... etc for all elements
                +"</Create_BB_Lead>";
```

Apart from that, this is a horrible and error prone way of constructing XML, it will eventually result in XML that is not well formed, causing
the recipient to fail in parsing it.

Use a real XML API (DOM, DOM4J or JDOM) to build the XML, or use JAXB.

Comment: Also `xml.replaceAll("$RqUID", req);` wouldn't replace anything since `$` is a special character in regex and must be escaped `xml.replaceAll("\\$RqUID", req);` or just use `xml.replace("$RqUID", req);` without regex.

Answer (score 0):

if you can't use velocity library, and want to avoid regular expressions, you could try using **java.text.MessageFormat** instead. for example

```
String xml = "<xml><content>"
                    + "<sender>{0}</sender>"
                    + "<email>{1}</email>"
                    + "<type>{2}</type>"
                    + "<date>{3}</date>"
                    + "<reply-to>{1}</reply-to>"
                + "</content></xml>";

         String[] values = {
           "Daniel", 
           "daniel@hi.com",
           "invoice #123", 
           "2018-03-22"
         };
         System.out.println(MessageFormat.format(xml, values));
```

this will print

```
<xml>
 <content>
   <sender>Daniel</sender>
   <email>daniel@hi.com</email>
   <type>invoice #123</type>
   <date>2018-03-22</date>
   <reply-to>daniel@hi.com</reply-to>
 </content>
</xml>
```

however,you should be careful with your String[] values order.